# Background Service Android Studio - disconnected from the service

Tags: android, service

I have a problem with my service in Android Studio.. In Run i get this:

> D/FA: Application going to the background
> V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

My code is :

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service{
//private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
String[] Radiouri = new String[50];
String[] NumeRadiouri = new String[50];
protected PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

void initializareRadiouri() {
    NumeRadiouri[1] = "Radio Ciresarii";
    NumeRadiouri[2] = "Radio Ekklesia";
    NumeRadiouri[3] = "Radio Filadelfia";
    NumeRadiouri[4] = "RVE Timisoara";
    NumeRadiouri[5] = "Radio Armonia";
    NumeRadiouri[7] = "RVE Sibiu";
    NumeRadiouri[6] = "Radio Gosen";
    NumeRadiouri[8] = "RVE Cluj";
    NumeRadiouri[9] = "Radio Calea spre Cer";
    NumeRadiouri[10] = "RVE Suceava";
    NumeRadiouri[11] = "Moody Radio Chicago";
    NumeRadiouri[12] = "Radio Crestin Autentic";
    NumeRadiouri[13] = "Radio Aripi spre Cer Predici";
    NumeRadiouri[14] = "Radio Aripi spre Cer";
    NumeRadiouri[15] = "Radio Micul Samaritean";
    NumeRadiouri[16] = "RVE International";
    NumeRadiouri[17] = "Radio Elim LIVE";
    NumeRadiouri[18] = "Radio Elim KIDS";
    NumeRadiouri[19] = "Radio Instrumental";
    NumeRadiouri[20] = "Radio Philadelphia Mansue";
    NumeRadiouri[21] = "Radio Levi";
    NumeRadiouri[22] = "Radio Unison";

    Radiouri[1] = "https://s3.radio.co/s6c0a773ad/listen";
    Radiouri[2] = "https://radio.namehost.ro/8005/stream";
    Radiouri[3] = "http://asculta.radiofiladelfia.ro:7000/stream_128.mp3";
    Radiouri[4] = "http://rvetm.infoo.ro:8624/rvetm.mp3";
    Radiouri[5] = "http://audio.radioarmoniaro.bisericilive.com/mainradioarmoniaro.mp3";
    Radiouri[6] = "http://ascultaradiogosen.no-ip.org:8125/";
    Radiouri[7] = "http://c13.radioboss.fm:8286/autodj";
    Radiouri[8] = "http://89.36.154.3:8000/stream.mp3";
    Radiouri[9] = "http://calea.radi0.im:8010/;";
    Radiouri[10] = "http://94.75.227.133:7280/;";
    Radiouri[11] = "http://primary.moodyradiostream.org:80/wmbifm.mp3";
    Radiouri[12] = "http://78.47.64.186:8082/radio/8000/radio.mp3?1590351182";
    Radiouri[13] = "http://aripisprecer.ro:8129/;?";
    Radiouri[14] = "http://aripisprecer.ro:8125/;";
    Radiouri[15] = "https://ssl-proxy.icastcenter.com/get.php?type=Shoutcast2&server=162.251.160.26&port=80&mount=&data=mp3";
    Radiouri[16] = "http://162.244.80.34:9648/stream/1/";
    Radiouri[17] = "http://91.213.11.102:8000/stream";
    Radiouri[18] = "http://91.213.11.102:8007/stream";
    Radiouri[19] = "http://aripisprecer.ro:8135/;stream.nsv";
    Radiouri[20] = "http://94.130.106.91/radio/8000/radio.mp3?1583393460;radio_philadelphia_contemporan.pls?sid=1";
    Radiouri[21] = "http://a1.bisericilive.com:8080/radioleviro.mp3";
    Radiouri[22] = "http://a1.bisericilive.com:8080/radiounisonro.mp3";
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "aplicatie3:Tag");

    super.onCreate();
    wl.acquire();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    initializareRadiouri();
    int radioId = intent.getIntExtra("RadioId", 0);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    //mediaPlayer.reset();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Radiouri[radioId]);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    wl.release();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
}
```

Where is the problem... after 5 seconds with my app in background...i see "Inactivity, disconnecting from the service" and after 2 minutes .. my radio stops. Please help me ... Thank you !

Comment: this might be closed by the android system to avoid leaks. Try to use Foreground Service instead

Comment: Thank you Zain ... so you're saying ... that a simple Backgrund Service would not help me to keep alive my service when my app is paused....also..i have Firebase ... but i don t use it... i have only Google Analytics.